# Indexing Slideshow Pages versus Indexing Individual Images

Tags: seo, google, images, google-index, google-image-search

My site is made up of a large content of resource images which are organized into groups shown in a Javascript slideshow. Only very small thumbnails are visible on the main web page itself.

If I were to let Google index the full size images individually, the resulting Google links would display only the image with no access to the slideshow or the web page on which the thumbnails are shown. Therefore, the link would allow downloading the image (right click, save image as) but this will not generate the traffic I want since the user will have no access to the web page the image is connected to.

My question: I could instead index each individual slideshow page with the current full sized image displayed on top and a filmstrip of thumbnails below. This would allow the full sized image to show in Google Images, but in an unconventional way - I've never seen anyone do this. Yet this would successfully also allow access to the web page context by clicking on Google's "Visit" link.
.
Other than being unconventional, any reason this is a bad idea? Is there any other way to connect a direct jpg link with the underlying web page for Google's "Visit" link if there is no direct link to the image on the web page?

UPDATE: Just a note on how to index individual Javascript slideshow pages: this is accomplished via providing a link which auto starts the Javascript slideshow and displays the correct image

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that [sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en) are the place for listing out images on a page. Then all I have to do is include in the sitemap.xml a single entry to the slideshow page and then list under it all the images included in the slideshow.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to provide an answer for what you figured out.